# Create new directory using contents of file

Tags: linux, bash, unix, scripting

In bash I have a file called temporary.txt that contains one line of text.  I want to use the contents of this line of text to create a new directory?  How can i do this?

Comment: `mkdir \`cat temporary.txt\``

Comment: @osgx: You must quote that, as in below answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
mkdir "$(< temporary.txt)"
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this which is less complex than the accepted answer.

```
mkdir `cat temp`
```

For each and every word in your text file this creates a directory.